# 1004 Error When Trying to Refresh Connections

Tags: excel, vba, connection

VBA refuses to refresh one of my queries. I've used:

```
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("address").Refresh
```

and recorded a macro that gave me:

```
    Sheets("Refresh").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
```

but I keep getting "Application-defined or object-defined error"

My parameters are good, manually refreshes work just fine, and my other VBA queries refresh no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following...

```
Sheets("Refresh").Range("A1").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

Comment: I tried 

    Sheets("Refresh").Range("A1").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

and now I get "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set.